# What are DuckDuckGo goodies?

Tags: search-engine, duckduckgo

I just discovered these cool looking '[goodies](https://duckduckgo.com/goodies)' on DuckDuckGo, but I have no idea how to use them, or what they are. Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: Perhaps you can add a screenshot or link? I can't see any goodies....

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra I also only found them by coincidence; request granted.

Comment: If you select "Programming", then it will show specific items programmer use (I guess). For example: Show IP address, generate a strong password.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra But how do I use them? It's somehow got something to do with some 'DuckDuckHack', but I don't know what that is either.

Comment: Did my answer help you to work with the goodies?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra Yes! I just misunderstood it first time, discovered what you wrote in your answer, and now I'd say your answer didn't help me in time, but it is the right answer, I'd just edit it a bit. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When going to the **[Goodies](https://duckduckgo.com/goodies)** and selecting the "programming" option, the following can be seen:
[image]

If you edit the field where "6GB/700KB/s in min" is mentioned and change it to "15GB/600KB/s in hour", then the following can bee seen:
[image]

So then if you type that in the main DDG search field, you get this:
[image]

Comment: Can't one somehow integrated so it does that from the main search field?

Comment: In this particular case, if you type "5GB/600KB/s in hour" in DDG, the answer will appear in the search result (calculated by WA).

Comment: But how do I do that integration?

Comment: @MadTux I showed you how to use them. Integrating them is a different question !!